# Add formula to a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula to input into a range. When I use a single cell range it's fine. However, when I try on a multi-cell range, it doesn't work. `Range("F1")` works and `Range("I4")` works but `Range("J4:EZ4")` does not. What am I missing?

````
    .ColumnWidth = 1
    .Range("F1").Formula = "=COUNT(I4:EZ4)"
    .Range("H5").Value = "Schedule Amount"
    .Range("I4").Formula = "=IF(($F$3-WEEKDAY($F$3,3)+IF(WEEKDAY($F$3,3)>4,11,4))>EOMONTH($F$3,0),EOMONTH($F$3,0),$F$3-WEEKDAY($F$3,3)+IF(WEEKDAY($F$3,3)>4,11,4))"
    .Range("J4:EZ4").Formula = "=IF(I4>$G$3,"",IF(AND(I4=EOMONTH(I4,0),WEEKDAY(I4)=6),EOMONTH(I4,0)+7,IF(I4=EOMONTH(I4,0),I4-WEEKDAY(I4,3)+IF(WEEKDAY(I4,3)>4,11,4),IF(MONTH(I4+7)<>MONTH(I4),EOMONTH(I4,0),I4+7))))"
    .Columns("D:EZ").AutoFit
    End With```
````

Comment: the `""` should be `""""`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks (as always)